# Parse credit card data using ID TECH UniPay Smart Card Reader

Tags: ios, encryption, smartcard-reader

I'm developing iOS app using ["UniPay, Mobile Audio Jack MagStripe and Smart Card Reader"](http://www.idtechproducts.com/products/mobile-readers/176.html/) 
to read smart credit card data.
I got the card data but it is not plain text, the SDK does not show how to parse the data. I have set the encryption mode to unencrypted mode. I guess the data is encoded in some kind of format. I have used the same decoding I use to parse magnetic stripe data but it did not work. does anyone know what kind of encoding is used or if the is kind of encrypted regards the flag i set. The following code is the example provided from SDK, I need to parse the rt.data to get credit card information such as card Number.

```
RDResult rt =[reader smart_ICC_PowerOn]; if (rt.status != RDS_SUCCESS) {
NSLog(@"ICC Powerd On - Failed.");
return; }
Else
{
NSLog(@"ICC Powered On: %@", rt.data.description); }
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: have you got the solution? i am looking for the same. If you found any solution please let me know.

Comment: Yes, I contacted their support and they guided me through it. I can not remember exactly but I needed to do another command before being able to read the data.

Comment: Hi @Sarah I am still not able to parse the data . Could you please help me out?

Comment: Have anyone got the solution? I am also stuck with parsing the credit card data from SDK.

Comment: @SudhinDavis, I contacted their support and they guided me through it. I can not remember exactly but I needed to do another command before being able to read the data. You can contact there tech-support from here http://www.idtechproducts.com/contact/tech-support

Comment: @Sarah Thank You Sarah. I too contacted them and found the solution.